# How to redirect user in mvc c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working on a multi-tenant project using Asp.Net MVC. I have created a custom route:

```
routes.Add("subdomain", new SubdomainRoute(
 domain: "{tenant}.example.com",
 url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}",
 defaults: new { tenant = "", controller = "Tenant", action = "Index", area = "Admin" }
));
```

I want to know how can i redirect user to this route. Means when user get registered i want to redirect him to subdomain *john.example.com/Admin/Dashboard/Index*. I tried:

> return RedirectToRoute(new { tenant = "john" });  //this not work
>
> return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard", new { tenant = model.Username, area = "Admin" }); //this result localhost:1025/Admin/Dashboard?tenant=john

BTW i have all required changes in host file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below way to redirect user from your Tenant controller.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return Redirect("http://john.example.com/Admin/Tenant/Index");
}
```

Comment: thanks it works but i want to know is this type of redirect comes under good coding practices ??

Comment: Yes it is, and the difference is Redirect(url) tells MVC to redirect to specified URL instead of rendering HTML. In this case, browser receives the redirect notification and make a new request for the specified URL. Please check this for more info http://niharstechnicalfunda.blogspot.in/2013/09/return-view-vs-return-redirecttoaction.html

Comment: i don't recommend to write the url inside the redirect unless its doesn't belong to your application for example google or yahoo or other domains that doesn't belong to your website, consider your RedirectToAction ( it will work fine) maybe the result coming localhost since you are testing the application locally by the visual studio, once you publish it the result will become as you want

Answer (score 0):

Try **RedirectToAction** method. Check this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx